# UIButton in UITableViewCell did not call the action

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uibutton

I have a UIButton in the UITableViewCell which i would like to toggle it's image when it got selected. Below is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)todoTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"SimpleTableIdentifier";

UITableViewCell *cell = [self.todoTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if(!cell)
    cell = [self getCellContentView:CellIdentifier];


UIImageView *checkboxView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:1];

UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 30.0, 30.0)];

UIImage *uncheckedButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked_checkbox.png"];
[button setImage:uncheckedButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[button addTarget:self action: @selector(toggleImage:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[checkboxView addSubview:button];
```

}`

and my toggleImage method is just:
`- (void)toggleImage
{
    NSLog(@"test");
}`

But whenever i click on the button itself, the row of cell gets called at didSelectRowAtIndexPath which i don't want, i want the button call the toggleImage method. Is it i set my button's action the wrong way?

Thanks.

Comment: why are you adding button in an UIImageView

Comment: I might get this wrong, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: you can direct add it to cell.contentView

Comment: ahh ok.. changed to UIView and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this `- (void)toggleImage { NSLog(@"test"); }` to

`- (void)toggleImage:(id)sender { NSLog(@"test"); }`and see if it works.

Comment: 7KV7, it didnt. Still clicking on the button within the cell call the cell's didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Answer (score 0):

7KV7 is right, you need to send the button object to the method in order to change the image of it.

Have a look at this thread

[how-to-select-particular-check-box-in-tableview-which-is-inserted-in-table-cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415732/how-to-select-particular-check-box-in-tableview-which-is-inserted-in-table-cell-i/5415843#5415843)